# External id field is not populating when cloning a sobject record

Tags: apex, map, sobject, clone

I have used object.clone() here and then changed some field values. All the changes are reflected in the cloned record except not able to populate External Id field which is concatenation of two Id fields Survey_Question_vod__c & ':' & Survey_Target_vod__c from the parent object.
Please suggest where it goes wrong.

```
if(s1qs2qMap.get(s1q1r.Survey_Question_vod__c)!=null && 
    s1Ts2TMap.get(s1q1r.Survey_Target_vod__c)!=null ) { 
    Question_Response_vod__c clonedRecord = s1q1r.clone();
    clonedRecord.Survey_Question_vod__c=s1qs2qMap.get(s1q1r.Survey_Question_vod__c);
    clonedRecord.Text_vod__c = s1q1r.Text_vod__c;
    clonedRecord.Type_vod__c = s1q1r.Type_vod__c;

    clonedRecord.Survey_Target_vod__c = s1Ts2TMap.get(s1q1r.Survey_Target_vod__c);
    clonedRecord.External_Id_vod__c = s1qs2qMap.get(s1q1r.Survey_Question_vod__c)+
        ':'+s1Ts2TMap.get(s1q1r.Survey_Target_vod__c);
    s2q1rListToInsert.add(clonedRecord);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of External Id ? I think it should be text, not ID

Comment: Yes it is a text field

Comment: what is the length ?

Comment: it has 120 size which is enough to incorporate two 18 digit Id field

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. If you change s1q1r.clone(); to new Question_Response_vod__c(); doesit work ?

Comment: How do you check, if its not populated, after insert? or in debug?

Comment: Can you try to print and check what is going inside ExternalId